# Motion of 'temperature-measuring device' w.r.t. to the object

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

A few days ago I had a discussion on the notion of temperature coming from the Kinetic theory of gas (KTG). I am applying the idea in below two cases.

***Case-I:*** Take the example of an ideal gas in a container. Suppose its temperature is measured with a suitable temperature-measuring device attached to it. Or, in other words, the measuring device is stationary w.r.t. to the centre of mass of our system.

It is well discussed in the literature on Statistical physics that:

> ***Fact-I***: The temperature of such a system doesn't depend on the motion of the container as a whole.

***Case-II:*** Now take a special case related to the same ideal gas system,

> This time the temperature-measuring device is moving w.r.t. the container.

So, I would like to know if **the temperature measured by the device in case-I and II would be the same or different.**

> I sense this will help us to write an alternative version of fact-I. I mean a definition of temperature more centred on the observer (a measuring device) instead of the centre of mass of the system.

Take it as a thought experiment. I am not much concerned about the practical realization of the system. I am more inclined toward how to make a consistent conclusion from the KTG model (the simplest model) for this ideal gas (the simplest case).

It seems necessary to specify how we are going to measure the temperature. I guess two potentially interesting methods would be-

> Method-I: (Non-contact thermometer) A device that measures the temperature by capturing the radiation emitted by the system. Say, a laser thermometer as suggested in the comment.

> Method-II: (Contact thermometer) A device that works by interacting with the system like a clinical thermometer. Say, a mercury thermometer (or any suitable substance).

Comment: I think this may depend on the specifics of how the temperature is measured.  That's not specified here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Temperature stops being especially meaningful as a predictor of work across the boundary if there are macroscopic collisions, deformations, friction, drag, etc, involved. Maybe specify a laser thermometer?